# There are at least four 3-dimensional subspace in $R^4$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Shouldn't there be EXACTLY four 3-dimensional subspaces in $R^4$?

My reasoning is that 3-d subspaces occur in $R^4$ when the rank of the augmented matrix of {$c_1:c_2:c_3:c_4$} is 3?

Comment: There slightly more than four $\;3-D$ subspace in $\;\Bbb R^4\;$ : about infinite. Any set of three linearly independent vectors will render one.

Comment: Hint: how many 1-dimensional subspaces are in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning must be wrong, because it is easy to list more than four different three-dimensional subspaces, such as these five:

$$\{\langle a,b,c,0\rangle\mid a,b,c\in \mathbb R\}$$
$$\{\langle a,b,0,c\rangle\mid a,b,c\in \mathbb R\}$$
$$\{\langle a,0,b,c\rangle\mid a,b,c\in \mathbb R\}$$
$$\{\langle 0,a,b,c\rangle\mid a,b,c\in \mathbb R\}$$
$$\{\langle a,a,b,c\rangle\mid a,b,c\in \mathbb R\}$$

(Which, by the way, works with any nontrivial ring in place of $\mathbb R$).

It may be instructive for you to examine exactly how the argument you're envisioning fails to prevent this particular set of subspaces from existing.